# Magento 2: Duplicate key-sequence unique identity-constraint 'uniqueVirtualType' fatal error while di:compile

Tags: magento2, collection, grid, custom, model

When i run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` it gives me below error

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException] Invalid Document
>   Element 'virtualType': Duplicate key-sequence
>   ['Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\Grid\Collection'] in
>   unique identity-constraint 'uniqueVirtualType'. Line: 80

My file **Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\Grid\Collection.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\Collection as MessagesCollection;

/**
 * Collection for displaying grid of etrade messages
 */
class Collection extends MessagesCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AggregationInterface
     */
    protected $aggregations;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param string $eventPrefix
     * @param string $eventObject
     * @param string $resourceModel
     * @param string $model
     * @param string|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            //$storeManager,
            //$metadataPool,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    /**
     * @return AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all ids for collection
     * Backward compatibility with EAV collection
     *
     * @param int $limit
     * @param int $offset
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

On Linux Server have i have PHP 7.X.X. In my Local i have PHP 5.X.X. So in Local No Issues. Only on the server having issue.

Comment: have you figured this out? I have the same issue. Element 'virtualType': Duplicate key-sequence ['Magento\Framework\Config\ValidationState\Required'] in unique identity-constraint 'uniqueVirtualType'.
Line: 1515